# How to get XML from DOC (not DOCX)?

Tags: python, xml, ms-word, docx, doc

For a DOCX document I do:

```
document = zipfile.ZipFile(path)
soup = BeautifulSoup(document.read('word/document.xml'), 'html.parser')
```

How to do this for DOC document?

Comment: The `.doc` file format is *not* XML-based - not clear what you're expecting to get here.....

Comment: I am trying to get highlighted text from word documents and am able to get which `w:r` are highlighted and in what color from the `xml`of the `.docx`. I want to do the same for `.doc`. Is there a way to not only get the string from the `.doc` but also the 'markup'/structure behind it?

Comment: You are in effect asking for a library to interpret the proprietary .doc format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You don't.

DOCX are tough enough to process, and they're XML-based and documented by international standards organizations.  DOC files are binary and proprietary.

Don't try to process DOC files directly.  **Convert them to DOCX first.**

**See:**

- [Convert .doc to .docx using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34111015/290085)
- [Automation: how to automate transforming .doc to .docx?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2405417/290085)
- [multiple .doc to .docx file conversion using python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38468442/290085)
- [Python & MS Word: Convert .doc to .docx?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42535066/290085)