# Convert old .doc format to the new .docx format on Linux?

Tags: linux, ms-word

Is there a command on Linux to convert an old MS Word document (.doc) to the new .docx format?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this question is just asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42535066/python-ms-word-convert-doc-to-docx), you can use following commands from this git [repository](https://github.com/unoconv/unoconv):

First install *unoconv*.

If you are using Ubuntu use this command:

```
sudo apt-get install unoconv
```

and go to your file location and run this command:

```
unoconv -d document --format=docx {your_file_name}.doc
```

or even if you want to format all *.doc* files there use this:

```
unoconv -d document --format=docx *.doc
```

hope this works for you.